# How to allow duplicates in StoredMap in BerkeleyDB?

Tags: java, dictionary, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

In the documentation for [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/collections/StoredMap.html) it mentions that somehow it is possible to allow duplicates. But I can not understand how. Can someone give me an example for this?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `DataBase` object, on the included `DataBaseConfig` call `setSortedDuplicates(true)` or `setUnsortedDuplicates(true)`. There's an example in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/db/Database.html).